# What lens do you think is used for this photo?

Tags: lens

What lens do you think is used for this photo?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx7eY.jpg]

Comment: It is impossible to tell. There are literally thousands of possibilities. Instead, could you describe what _particular_ thing you'd like to accomplish that you see in this picture? We can then help you figure out what kind of equipment will be useful.

Comment: Why do you think a particular lens achieved this shot? This shot looks like it was achieved with a faster shutter speed, high ISO and then focussed on the shoulder then with a reasonable aperture to achieve DOF.

Answer (score 6):

There's no way to tell the exact lens that was used by looking at most photos. But there are some clues that can help us guess what *type* of lens was used.

In the linked photo the perspective indicates the photo was taken from a fairly close distance. The elbow appears to be almost the same size as the subject's head! That indicates the distance from the camera to the elbow was probably less than 35-50% of the distance from the camera to the subject's head. This means the camera was likely no further than about two or three feet from the shoulder that is in focus.

To get that much of a person in the frame at such a close distance, a fairly wide angle lens must be used. Something like a 24-28-35mm on a full frame body, Or a 14-18-24mm on an APS-C crop body.

To get such shallow depth of field at such close distance, the lens had to have a very wide aperture  - something in the neighborhood of f/1.4 to f/2 for FF, or f/0.9 to f/1.4 on a crop body.

So that leaves us with something like a 24mm f/1.4, 28mm f/1.8, or a 35mm f/1.4 prime lens on a FF camera. In my opinion the most likely candidate is a 24/1.4. Several lens makers offer such lenses and some of them, such as the Canon EF 24mm f/1.4 L II or the Sigma 24mm f/1.4 DG ART, are perfectly capable of pulling off such a shot in the hands of a capable shooter.

At three feet focusing distance a 24mm lens at f/1.4 on a full frame camera gives a depth of field of around 5 inches at the display size and distance that I am viewing the sample image on my monitor.